# How to remove public? from url in php project

Tags: .htaccess

I am currently working to build a small php mvc framework. in a framework i have a this folder structure.

```
-app
  --controllers
    -Post.php
-core
-logs
-public
  --.htaccess
  -- index.php
-vendor
```

in here index.php is working as Front Controller

in post controller is look like this..

```
<?php

/**
 * Posts controller
 *
 */
class Posts
{

    public function index()
    {
        echo 'Hello index';
    }

    public function addNew()
    {
        echo 'Hello addNew';
    }
}
```

in url, i want to remove `project/public/?posts/index` **public/?**. When i remove (public/?) and visit the url. its showing me this error message.

```
project/posts/index
```

> The requested URL was not found on this server.

using **public/?** `project/public/?posts/index` is working fine. and its echo index message

### project/public/

The `.htaccess` inside of the public folder contains:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

in project main root folder ...
i did't added .htaccess and index.php file.

in .htaccess when i add this line. url redirect to xammp welcome screen

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Your question is completely vague and unclear. You certainly cannot simply snip out a bit of a URL and then expect it to delivery the same response as before. So why do you think `/project` and `/project/public` should point to the same resource?

Comment: sorry about that, I am new here and its my first question. I have updated the question and added more details about the issue. if you have any solution regarding this question, please help. I really appreciate it. thanks

Comment: My question remains the same: why do you expect that you can simply leave out something from the URL but that it still points to the same resource? Without the "public" in the URL, how should that request be processed? By which logic or router? There is none in the requested folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say you want to internally rewrite all incoming requests to the controller inside the `/project/public` folder. But that is not what you do. The rule you implemented (`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]`) only rewrites *relative* to the requested folder. No mentioning of "public" in there.

The actual setup you need depends a bit on your http host setup here. Where its `DOCUMENT_ROOT` points to. Most likely to the folder that contains the file system structure you posted in your question. If so you should implement a rule that rewrites all incoming requests to the `/project/public` folder.

Something like that, though you probably need to tweak it to match your actual setup:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^ /public/index.php?%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]
```

You can implement such rule in the http server's host configuration. Or, if you do not have access to that, you can use a *distributed* configuration file (if you have enabled those for the http host), so a ".htaccess" style file. That file should be located inside the folder your http hosts `DOCUMENT_ROOT` setting points to. So the folder containing the file system structure your posted.

Other setups are possible, this is just one option. The point is: you need to rewrite the requests to your controller. Where the controller actually is.

Comment: thanks for your help. you are right.. i think in my xampp config has not correct. i just change xampp to laragon. and the issue was solve. http://project.test/posts/index is now working as i expecting...

Comment: I have no idea what that actually means, but it is great to hear that you solved your issues!